# How to use ScalaMock not in the tests?

Tags: scala, scalamock

Is this possible to use ScalaMock stub not inside the tests but inside actual code? I want to run http service that require other service witch I want to stub for now. Can't find in documentation how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a difference in behavior between runtime and test environment, when it comes to dependency management and bytecode. Only difference would be what dependencies are defined for each of them. I assume that simply removing `Test` from:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.5.0" % Test
```

should do the job. Personally though, I would prefer to write a stub service by hand.

Comment: Note that this will also pull in Scalatest into your production code. you could probably just depend on `scalamock-core` if you don't want that. ScalaMock wasn't really designed for this use-case - might be an idea to use Scala.meta directly: http://scalameta.org/